# Set of Compatible Observables and Simultaneous Eigenkets Basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, mathematical-physics, commutator

I have managed to prove that a **finite** set of compatible observables [i.e. pairwise commuting (possibly unbounded) selfadjoint operators] on an Hilbert space $\{H\}$ admits an orthonormal basis of simultaneous eigenkets by proceeding by induction on the number of observables and by constructing the required basis piecewise, starting from each eigenspace of the last operator in the set.

I would like to know if one can generalize this Theorem to an **arbitrary** family of compatible observables on $\{H\}$. I tried doing it by extending my own proof: instead of using induction we may use transfinite induction, however in that case we have the problem of dealing with limit ordinals.